# present UIImagePickerController from collectionViewCell class

Tags: swift, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a little trouble presenting the UIImagePicker from a collectionViewCell. I know collectionViewCells do not act as the picker delegate by default so I did try to call a method from the UIViewController class operating the cell holding the imageView tapped. There are no errors showing in my console, but when I run the app and try to present the UIImagePickerController nothing happens and I receive the "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". I would like to present the UIImagePickerController when user taps on the profileImageView. Thanks in advance for help!

// LoginCell class holding the imageView to call the UIImagePickerController method from LoginController class

```
       lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
         imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return imageView
        }() 

        var loginController: LoginController?

        func handleSelectProfileImage() {
        let loginController = LoginController()
        loginController.showImagePicker(sendingVC: loginController)
    }
```

// LoginController class as UIImagePickerController delegate

```
    func showImagePicker(sendingVC: LoginController) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath) as! LoginCell
            loginCell.delegate = self
            return loginCell
 }
```

Comment: have you set loginController?

Comment: I did, see updated code as well. I am now getting the warning message about window hierarchy.

Comment: If your UICollectionView is in your LoginViewController, you should set a reference to the LoginViewController in cellForItemAtIndexPath, not creating a new LoginController instance.

Comment: Ok, makes sense thanks. So my loginCell has always been set to the delegate in the cellForItemAtIndexPath. My app still crashes when I try to present UIImagePickerController from LoginCell as the delegate. See updated code in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, in your cell:

```
func handleSelectProfileImage() {

    guard let loginController = delegate as? LoginViewController else {
        return
    }

    loginController.showImagePicker()
}
```

in your LoginController

```
func showImagePicker() {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```